# PROC SQL to remove duplicate pairs of observations?

Tags: sas, duplicates, proc-sql

[image]I need to remove observations with duplicate pairs (ie. the original observation and it's duplicate). I have more than hundred columns, but sometimes for a given ID I am getting a pair of different Load_Date and a pair of Contactor columns.
The below code I am using to remove all cases when I have duplicate pairs as described above[image]:

Could you let me know if I am doing it the right way? From the described data, I need to keep records for ID value C and D only. I did check my output and it looks like it worked, still not sure because I am new to proc sql. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to completely remove duplicates, or do you want to keep one of them?

Comment: I want to completely remove the duplicates, but here we aren't just talking about keeping one of the dups. I want to remove the pair of observations that had the duplicate and it's original.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to use PROC SQL for this?

Comment: Just thinking it's easier. But if you could offer a better way I would appreciate it.

Comment: Also, for non-sas SQL folks, SAS will allow selecting non-group by fields (differing from many implementations); it will perform the GROUP BY with those fields and then join back to the original data (thus likely returning more rows than the `group by` would).

Comment: As far as load date and contractor, are you removing records with *both* duplicated, or any pair of record duplicating *either* field?  Sample data would be helpful.

Comment: I just added a sample dataset. I need an output with ID values C and D. Yes, the load date and contractor are always different. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

SAS solution, assuming you want only want to remove records duplicating `ID`.

```
proc sort data=have;
by ID;
run;

data want;
set have;
by ID;
if first.ID and last.ID;
run;
```

This removes records that are identical for ID.  If VAR1 and VAR2 are also relevant, you could add those as well to the sort; the `FIRST` and `LAST` should be the rightmost variable in the `by` statement.

Comment: Unfortunately this code doesn't give me ID's C and D as an output.

Comment: Left out `by` statement, sorry - try now.

Answer (score 1):

And a proc SQL solution.  Same output, but one step and no explicit sorting.

```
proc sql; 
    create table WANT as
    SELECT *
    FROM have
    GROUP BY ID
    /* Put your criteria here, can use any COUNT DISTINCT*/
    HAVING COUNT(*)=1
;quit;
```